# What's the default inheritant type of a member function in PHP?

Tags: php, member-functions

```
class foo implements Countable {

    function count() {
        # do stuff here
    }
}
```

What's the type of `count`,public,protect or private?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Class methods may be defined as public, private, or protected. Methods declared without any explicit visibility keyword are defined as **public**.

Same behaviors also apply for class properties.

Taken from [**PHP: Visibility**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

As Bart has noted in his comment, although PHP will assign the visibility for you (*if one is not explicitly assigned*), it is strongly recommended for good practice and coding standards to assign the visibility for yourself.

Comment: This is true, but I would also add that you should always make it a point to explicitly specify the visibility. It's just good practice.

Answer (score 0):

It's type is `public`. In php if you don't specify scope for methods, it is assumed **public**.

Answer (score 0):

Public....unless specified otherwise.